# wordpress post link to category

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been searching for a result on google, but I haven't succeeded yet :( .

I'm trying to change the destination of a post link within wordpress.
I have a link to a category page, this category gets (at the moment, but not limited to...) 3 posts.
What I would like is that those posts each link to another category when clicked. But i dont want the links to be hard coded, so i could change to what category they link at any time.

Is there a way to make this work? Or is there a (fairly simple) alternative way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Your posts act like categories. So why should a link to a post redirect to a category page (this question is rethorical - semantically it just shouldn't)?

You should try to define your system via categories and subcategories. Wordpress offers huge functionalities for this system and there are plugins out there if you want to extend your categories with additional post-like content (thumbnails, formatted descriptions, etc.).

If you need user interaction you can easily build a form with ACF, NinjaForms / GravityForms where other people can add such category items.

I really don't want to be rude - but having posts that actually link to categories instead of behaving like posts sounds just wrong.